# Managing a pair of files as one in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, diff, mercurial-extension

I'm working with small binary files in Mercurial as [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707087/automatic-conversion-of-specific-binary-files-to-text-to-compare-diff-in-mercur).

This binary files can be dumped as text to make a diff between versions, but the problem is that the files comes in pairs (eg: Form.scx / Form.sct), and I cannot found a way to tell Mercurial to "make a snapshot" (copy to a temporary location) of the other corresponding file when I do an `hg ediff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Ryan, I ended up with a *small* batch previous to the diff program:

```
@echo off
set f1=%1
set f2=%2
::Temporary dir created by hg to copy the snapshot file
set tdir=%~dp1
::Original repository dir
set repo=%~dp2
::Filename extension
set ext=%~x1
::The binary files comes in pairs: scx/sct \ vcx/vct ...
set ex2=%ext:~0,-1%t

::Check if "dumpable" extension
echo %ext% | grep -iE "(vcx|vct|scx|sct|pjx|pjt|frx|frt)" > nul && goto DumpFile
goto diff

:DumpFile
set f1="%tdir%\_Dump1.prg"
set f2="%tdir%\_Dump2.prg"
::Get the pair file from the repository
hg cat %repo%\%~n1%ex2% -o "%~dpn1%ex2%" -R %repo%

::Do the dump, then the diff
MyDumpProgram.exe %1 %f1%
MyDumpProgram.exe %2 %f2%
goto diff

:diff
ExamDiff.exe %f1% %f2%
pause
```

and then config the batch in %UserProfile%\.hgrc

```
[extdiff]
cmd.ediff = d:\Utiles\diff2.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make a quick script and set that as the tool for extdiff.  I'm guessing you're on Windows, but whatever the powershell equivalent to this is:

```
#!/bin/sh
binary-to-text $1 /tmp/$1.sct
binary-to-text $2 /tmp/$2.sct
diff /tmp/$1.sct /tmp/$2.sct
rm /tmp/$1.sct /tmp/$2.sct
```

That creates, compares, and then deletes the text versions.  You'd want to be careful to not overwrite, deal with multiple concurrent invocations, etc.

Then configure a new command to run your script:

```
[extdiff]
cmd.mydiff = that_script_above.sh
```

Then you can do things like:

```
hg mydiff
```

Ideally you have only the "source" bonary format in your respository, not the text format, as you shouldn't keep generated items in the repo -- because if you update one but not the other you have an inconsistent state.  Generating the comparable text files on demand is a better way to go.